# Lines and perpendicular planes

Tags: vectors

Find the equation of the plane that passes through the point $(5, 1, 2)$ and is
perpendicular to the line $2x-4 = y-4  = z-5$. Find also the coordinates of the 
point where the line cuts the plane.

---

This question seems to confuse me a little bit due to the point (5, 1, 2) being mentioned. I'm not sure whether it is used in the first or second *(or both..)* part of the problem.

I do know that $r . a = r . n $ however since it's perpendicular the dot-product must be equal to 0. The asnwer I got are as follows:

*Equation of the plane:* $$r . (5i + j + 2k) = 0$$

My value for parameter $t$ was $-3$

And $\therefore$ my point of intersection was *(-1, 1, 2)*

---

The reason why I ask this question is because I highly doubt it is correct. If by whatever miracle it is, I'll close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formula for a plane is
$$
a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0
$$
where $(a,b,c)$ is a vector perpendicular to the plane and $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a point on the plane.  Note that this is the same as
$$
(a,b,c)\cdot(x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0)=0.
$$
To find the point of intersection, you need to parameterize your line and plug that into the equation for your plane.  You can do this by solving for all the variables in terms of one of them:
$$
z=2x+1
$$
and
$$
y=2x.
$$
So, that
$$
x=t, y=2t, z=2t+1.
$$

Comment: So $(a,b,c)$ could be the direction vector of the line and thus Point A could by my $x_{0}, y_{0}, z_{0}$?

Comment: The problem that comes to hand is figuring out which vectors to plug in where

Comment: @Juxhin Yes, $(a,b,c)$ is the direction vector of the line and the point is the other.  Don't forget that you need to translate the line to go through the origin first.